# The method is being applied wrong elements in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, custom-adapter

I have a problem about listview. Each item of listview have an imageview  and a textview. I extended BaseAdapter class for Listview adapter and overrided some methods that I must override. By the way I want to shrink the size of text in the textview if greater than 25. For this reason I created a method whose name is "shrinkText()". When I execute the application first time, this method works correctly.So the textviews whose size of text grater than 25 have been shrinked and other textviews keep their size. However, when I scrool down the listview, textviews that their text size less than 25 have been shrinked too. What should I do to fix this? Thanks

My listview adapter...

```
 public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


      private final ProgramInfo values;
      private LayoutInflater mInflater;

       public ListAdapter(Context context, ProgramInfo values) {

        this.values = values;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      }

       @Override
       public int getCount(){

           return values.getSize();
    }
       @Override
       public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

       @Override
       public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder; 

            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.brd_stream_list_item,parent,false);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.p_Name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.prgName);
                viewHolder.p_Image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.prgImage);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            }else{

                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.p_Name.setText(values.programNames.get(position));
            viewHolder.p_Image.setImageResource(R.drawable.alarm_clock_ed);


           CharSequence text = viewHolder.p_Name.getText(); 
           shrinkText(text,viewHolder.p_Name); //Call for shrink

         }
```

My shrinkText() method..

```
private void shrinkText(CharSequence text, TextView v){

if(text.length()>25){

    v.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 11);

    }
}
```

Comment: rename `shrinkText` to `toShrinkOrNotToShrinkText` :)  .... and of course add `else` stament to reflect its new name ...

Comment: @Selvin My answer in a comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the else statement :

```
private void shrinkText(CharSequence text, TextView v){

if(text.length()>25){

    v.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 11);

    }
else {
   v.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25); //the default text size
}
}
```

A tips : to avoid bug, always use `if-else` statement in `getView` (not only `if`).

Comment: I added else statement and it is working correctly thank you :)